Azure Devops custom pipeline task updating to new version passed verification but actually failed without any error and not using updated version
This question is about writing custom pipeline task for Azure DevOps Server (On Premises) (Add a custom pipelines task extension). I wrote my task with PowerShell and installed it and it's working well but updating to new version (patch number) not worked. Updating to new patch version was successful and verified OK, and in Manage Extensions page shows the new version is installed, either in Installed extensions page. But in pipeline definition It not accepts to save definition of a pipeline with new version and says task is missing also agents not using new version and still using old version.
This process was successful for previous versions of this task, and updating of it occurred many times but at this new version failed.
How can I debug the Update process of extension to new version?
Where can I see the log if any exists?
I tried to install it with tfx cli but other problems stopped me like error: unable to get local issuer certificate
(Azure DevOps Server 2022.2 ver: 20240702.1)
Update - Workaround:
Restarting the Azure DevOps Server solved the problem, and some of uploaded patch versions now available to use but not all of them, and more importantly, this is not a conventional solution.

Please ensure that the version in your task.json file has been updated and your extension is created based on the new version.

The version you see in Installed extensions page and Manage Extensions page is the version of your extension, which is defined in vss-extension.json.

If I update the version in vss-extension.json, but not in task.json, I will reproduce your issue.

Update:
Solution (shared by @AhmadYo):
Restarting the Azure DevOps Server solved the problem.
Restarting the server can force all services and applications to reload, ensuring that the new version of your extension is properly initialized and running.

Both are updated and although not necessary, they are the same number.

Hi @AhmadYo, thanks for your update. I noticed that you said the issue was resolved by restarting the Azure DevOps Server. Restarting the server can force all services and applications to reload, ensuring that the new version of your extension is properly initialized and running. You can monitor it and see if you will have the same issue again. To help others who may have the same problem, I update your solution in the answer above.

Hi @Ziyang, Yes this solved part of the problem, but it's not a conventional solution. We don't always have the possibility to reset Azure Server. I think there might be a better solution and I continue to search for it.

Have you tried to uninstall the extension and reinstall it? If not, you can try this when you have the same issue again.

No, uninstalling causes fail on all pipelines and if Installing after that fail it would be a disaster situation and not a practical solution.

I suggest you monitor to see whether you will have the same issue when you update to the next version. If so, you can share the smallest sample that reproduces the issue so I and other members in the community can check and investigate further.
